# how to loop an array in string in a where clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an information table with a column of an array in string format. The length is unknown starting from 0. How can I put it in a where clause of PostgreSQL?

```markdown
* hospital_information_table
| ID  | main_name  | alternative_name  |
| --- | ---------- | ----------------- |
| 111 | 'abc'      | 'abe, abx'        |
| 222 | 'bbc'      | ''                |
| 333 | 'cbc'      | 'cbe,cbd,cbf,cbg' |
​
​
* record
| ID  | name    | hospital_id  |
| --- | ------- | ------------ |
| 1   | 'abc-1' |              |
| 2   | 'bbe+2' |              |
| 3   | 'cbf*3' |              |
​
```

e.g. this column is for alternative names of hospitals. let's say e.g. 'abc,abd,abe,abf' as column Name and '111' as ID. And I have a record with a hospital name 'cbf*3' ('3' is the department name) and I would like to check its ID. How can I check all names one by one in 'cbe,cbd,cbf,cbg' and get its ID '333'?

--update--

In the example, in the record table, I used '-', '*', '+', meaning that I couldn't split the name in the record table under a certain pattern. But I can make sure that some of the alternative names may appear in the record name (as a substring). something similar to e.g. 'cbf' in 'cbf*3'. I would like to check all names, if 'abe' in 'cbf*3'? no, if 'abx' in 'cbf*3'? no, then the next row etc.

--update--

Thanks for the answers! They are great!
For more details, the original dataset is not in alphabetic languages. The text in the record name is not separable. it is really hard to find a separator or many separators. Therefore, for the solutions with regrex like '[-*+]' could not work here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking SQL questions. Make it easy to assist you!

Comment: That column needs to be a separate table, perhaps named "AlternativeNames", of (HospitalID, Name) with separate rows for each possible name for an ID. Then the query would be `SELECT HospitalID FROM AlternativeNames WHERE Name = $1` and add the name as a parameter in a prepared statement.

Comment: This question is unanswerable in its current form! Please provide a link to dbfiddle.uk and give us the necessary info and your desired result and the logic you used to arrive at your result!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `regexp_split_to_array` to convert the coma-delimited string to a proper array, and then use the `any` operator to search inside it:

```sql
SELECT r.*, h.id
FROM   record r
JOIN   hospital_information h ON 
       SPLIT_PART(r.name, '-', 1) = ANY(REGEXP_SPLIT_TO_ARRAY(h.name, ','))
```

**[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/480a45/4/0)**

Comment: I suspect the OP also needs `OR SPLIT_PART(r.name, '-', 1) = h.main_name`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. The solution slightly doesn't match my situation. I updated more details and please have a look at it if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Substring can be used with a regular expression to get the hospital name from the record's name.

And String_to_array can transform a CSV string to an array.

> ```
> SELECT 
>   r.id as record_id
> , r.name as record_name
> , h.id as hospital_id
> FROM record r
> LEFT JOIN hospital_information h
>   ON SUBSTRING(r.name from '^(.*)[+*\-]\w+$') = ANY(STRING_TO_ARRAY(h.alternative_name,',')||h.main_name)
> WHERE r.hospital_id IS NULL;
> ```

| record_id | record_name | hospital_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc-1 | 111 |
| 2 | bbe+2 | 222 |
| 3 | cbf*3 | 333 |

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=da6059bea734ed1746fbcd2895962def)*

*Btw, `text []` can be used as a datatype in a table.*